# meteor test equality of a input value to a document field

Tags: meteor

Hello: I’m  using the Tutorials todo.
I’ve been trying to compare an Input value

```
<input type="text" name="text" placeholder="Type Or Scan to add new Name" />
```

To the field named ‘text’ within a Document named ‘Tasks’.
Have tried EasySearch and `{{#if $eq a b}}   ...  {{ /if }}`.
May because I’m new to Meteor not setting up `<templates>` correctly.
Was hoping there is a short template or helper to compare or check the values to.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using a [reactive variable](https://atmospherejs.com/meteor/reactive-var).

Here's some example code:

JS:

```
Template.yourTemplateName.onCreated( function() {
    this.input = new ReactiveVar(""); // Declare the reactive variable.
});

Template.yourTemplateName.helpers({
    tasks() {
        return Tasks.find(); // Find all tasks as an example.
    },
    isInputEqualToTaskText( taskId ) {
        var task = Tasks.findOne({ _id: taskId });
        if( task && task.text ) {
            return task.text == Template.instance().input.get();
        }
    }
});

Template.yourTemplateName.events({
    'change input': function( event, template ) {
        template.input.set(event.target.value);
    }
});
```

HTML:

```
<template name="yourTemplateName">
    {{#each task in tasks}}
        {{#if isInputEqualToTaskText task._id}}
           <p>I was equal: {{task.text}}</p>
        {{/if}}
    {{/each}}
    <input type="text">
</template>
```